# Scripts and Stylesheet don't works in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I starting now with Zend Framework 2, so i'm learning how to use this yet. I'm trying to construct a layout.phtml page like bellow:

```
<?php echo $this->doctype(); ?>

<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- Title Head -->
        <?php
        $NAME_APPLICATION = 'Enquete';        
        var_dump($this);
        echo $this
                ->headTitle($NAME_APPLICATION)
                ->setSeparator(' - ')
                ->setAutoEscape(false)
        ;
        ?>

        <!-- Meta Head -->
        <?php
        echo $this
                ->headMeta()
                ->appendName('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
                ->appendHttpEquiv('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=edge')
        ;
        ?>

        <!-- Styles -->
        <?php
        echo $this
                ->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico'))
                ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/style.css')
                ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
                ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        ;
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Início</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h3 class="text-muted"><?php echo $NAME_APPLICATION; ?></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="row marketing">
                <?php echo $this->content; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="footer">
                <p class="muted credit pull-left">Company <a href="">© 2013</a></p>
                <p class="muted credit pull-right">Desenvolvido por <a href="http://igorrocha.com.br">Igor Rocha</a>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <?php
        echo $this
                ->headScript()
                ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js')
                ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.min.js')
                ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/respond.min.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
                ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/html5shiv.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
        ;

        echo $this->inlineScript();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have only a module called "Enquete", but when i try access from : "localhost/myproject/public" this scripts and stylesheets aren't rendered, see what appers:

```
<div class="topo-table">
    <a class="btn btn-success" title="Novo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>

    <div class="btn-group" title="Quantidades por PÃ¡gina">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">005</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" style="min-width: 75px" role="menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">005</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">010</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">025</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">050</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">100</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <form class="form-inline pull-right" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="localizar">Buscar...</label>
            <input type="search" class="form-control" id="localizar" placeholder="Bucar...">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </form>
</div>

<br />

<div class="corpo-table">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Tel. Principal</th>
                <th>Tel. Qua.</th>
                <th>Data CriaÃ§Ã£o</th>  
                <th>AÃ§Ã£o</th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Fortaleza CearÃ¡ Brasil</td>
                    <td>(085)85858585</td>
                    <td class="text-center">2</td>
                    <td>
```

**My module.config.php**

```
<?php

return array(
    # definir e gerenciar controllers
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'HomeController' => 'Enquete\Controller\HomeController'
        ),
    ),

    # definir e gerenciar rotas
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type'      => 'Literal',
                'options'   => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'HomeController',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    # definir e gerenciar servicos
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            #'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),

    # definir e gerenciar layouts, erros, exceptions, doctype base
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason'  => true,
        'display_exceptions'        => true,
        'doctype'                   => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'        => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'        => 'error/index',
        'template_map'              => array(
            'layout/layout'         => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'enquete/home/index'    => __DIR__ . '/../view/enquete/home/index.phtml',
            'error/404'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with two methods:

1. Put all your .css and .js files in the main public folder (which is outside your module) and you can use like this:

   ```
   prependFile($this->basePath() . '/css/abc.css')
   ```
2. You can fork [this module](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager), then you can create a public folder in your module and put your .css/.js files in it.

Comment: This files already inside public folder, outside my module folder

Comment: Have you added info. for linking layout file in module.config.php file?

Comment: The config file seems to be correct, so when you run the module you get the output but its style is not correct or you don't get any output at all?

Comment: I just get the pure html without scripts or styles as i showed in post.